# Python dynamically increment number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have requirement to show the current number of job completed without printing status of each job every time. for example,  I have 100 job posting running in `for loop` and before starting the `for loop` I'll show print message job number "1" started, here is the sample code

```
i = 1
print(f "Job number {i} posted successfully")
for i in range(100):
     i += 1
```

I want my print message  `Job number 1 posted successfully`  , here `1` value of `I` should auto increment after each job posting in `for loop` . I don't want to put `print` in for loop to print 100 message.  Is there anyway it can be achieved in python?

Comment: Maybe if you put the `print()` line into the loop and use an f-string.

Comment: So you want to call `print`, run the loop and then somehow modify the output without calling `print` again?

Comment: The loop inherently sets `i` to 0 then increments it; even if you incremented or set `i` to 1 before the loop then it would still be set to 0 and increment to 99.

Comment: @balmy , I have one job where i am sending to other api in for loop and want to see how many has been job sent rather printing each job number. just avoiding multiple ```print``` for each job posting.

Comment: `range(100)` starts at 0 and increments to 99. If you want to start at a different initial value then read the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range

Comment: so you want that your printed msj update each time `i` change but without printing it in a new line?

Comment: @Copperfield, Yes. is there anyway to do this?

Comment: there certainly are, that is how libraries such as tqdm do it progress bar on console and what not.... give a second to find it...

Comment: It’s not clear why printing the variable should increment it; if you then removed the print perhaps because you wanted to not have printing then the variable wouldn’t be incremented; surely you’re going to use a for loop which uses `range` or increments the variable. Sorry but your question doesn’t make sense. Maybe this is an x-y problem; what are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @balmy,  I updated my question in post. hope it make sense now.

Comment: Actually no it still doesn’t make sense. Why don’t you try to show in code and output what you want to happen. Don’t start from your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a progress bar of sort, I recommend the [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) library, is my favorite.

Now for printing in the same line as before is simple, you need to print the `\r` character.

Simple example

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    print("\r","updating",i,end="")
    time.sleep(1) #we put it to sleep so we can see the change gradually
```

This should print the that text in the same line, in your console so long that console support it, for example the IDLE console of python doesn't support it so this trick would not work there.

Important here is to also said to print that we don't want to go to the next line, which is the default, to change that is simple give the keyword only argument `end` and set it to an empty string.

**Edit Note:** So long the text you're printing is the same or greater length than the previously printed one there will no problem, if it get shorted then there will be left over from the previous text that don't get overwritten and will messed up the msj, so see this just check this sample

```
for i in reversed(range(102)):
    print("\r","updating",i,end="")
    time.sleep(1) #we put it to sleep so we can see the change gradually
```

if that become a problem, simple adding some white space at the end equal to the difference will solve it.